# React-Native: border is jagged in Android

Tags: android, react-native, border

I am building an application in **React-Native**. I used below code to make my view rounded and give radius to it. It's work perfectly on iOS. But I used the same code in Android **borderRadius** be jaggedgged.

```
<View
     style={
        height: 100,
        width: 100,                            
        borderRadius: 50,     
        backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
        marginBottom: 0,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'lightgray',        
    }
/>
```

[image]

Any Solutions?

Comment: Try platform conditional width and height or use the inspector

Comment: Height and width is fine. The issue in border radius.

Comment: Try using the inspector if you are using expo and `It's work perfectly on iOS.` Then add an image

Comment: Seems like a long term issue as mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17267), due to fail in antiAliasing in the view tag

Answer (score -1):

as Pritish's comment above mentions/links to, you can try

```
overflow: 'hidden',
```

in your style. It worked for me on iOS when I had the same issue.

Comment: still shows up pixellated, even with overflow hidden

Comment: which React Native version? and do you have a snippet of your code?